# Adobe Animate Actionscript calculator, saving numbers after a symbol as an int/string

Tags: flash

I need to somehow make the numbers after +,-,*,/ into an variable "num2"
Any ideas? I am a beginner in actionscript and couldn't find any solution in the book or on the web :/
Added the Java tag because the flash section is nearly dead, and I believe the solution would be same in both languages, if I'm wrong tell me and I'll remove the tag ;)

[image]

```
    function equals(evt:MouseEvent) {
    if (action == plus) {
        text_field.text = text_field.text + "=" + (num1 + num2);
    }
    else if (action == minus) {
        text_field.text = text_field.text + "=" + (num1 - num2);
    }
    else if (action == divide) {
        text_field.text = text_field.text + "=" + (num1 / num2);
    }
    else if (action == multiply) {
        text_field.text = text_field.text + "=" + (num1 * num2);
    }
}
function plus(evt:MouseEvent) {
    action = plus;
    num1 = parseInt(text_field.text);
    text_field.text = text_field.text + '+';
}
```

Comment: cute design for calculator!

Comment: Why not accept the posted Answer? You can just create a new array and say `myArray = parse_values(text_field.text)` and from there you'll get 2533 in the array's [0] index and next numerical value at [1] index and so on... Basically `num2 = myArray[1];` has same result as `num2 = 33`... etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i suggest spliting input text by operators or even all of non numerical characters like me, using regular expression

```
// returns an array of values
function parse_values(inputString:String):Array {
    return inputString.split(/[^0-9]/);
}
```

for example :

```
var cinput:String = "333+663/2345-6554";
trace(parse_values(cinput));
```

and result :

```
333,663,2345,6554
```

### Edit:

also for future question like detecting parentheses, non integer numbers etc..
your Answer is : **[RegularExpression](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f97.html)**